# Como puedo abrir 2 ventanas de Visual Studio Code de un mismo proyecto pero de ramas distintas?

Tags: git, vscode, github

Quiero que cada ventana de VSC tenga 2 ramas distintas del mismo proyecto para compararlas o alguna alternativa que me permita hacerlo sin tener que ver el código en GitHub.

Comment: No estoy seguro que se pueda hacer eso, pero tal vez haya una extensión para eso

Comment: Estás buscado algo como `git diff` pero en visual studio Code?

Comment: No sé para qué quieres dos ventanas abiertas a la vez, pero prueba con [Git Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) a ver si te sirve.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes descargarte dos veces el proyecto y tener dos ventanas del vscode cada una con el proyecto descargado, para abrir dos ventanas el shortcut es ctrl+shift+N

Comment: Una solución algo rara pero efectiva, me gisto tu punto de vista

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, lo probe y esta genial, fijate en:
https://ed.team/blog/trabaja-en-dos-o-mas-ramas-de-git-al-mismo-tiempo

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/331273)

Comment: Excelente lo llevare en cuenta en proximos posteos gracias.

Comment: No lo tengas en cuenta "para futuros posteos"... Empieza por corregir esta respuesta :) Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.